# Dynamic allocation of list in STL and element insertion

Tags: c++, list, c++11, stl

The following code is ought to read a a number of nodes in a graph, and then a certain number of edges which will be introduced in a dynamically allocated list of adjacent nodes. For some reason the program halts when calling `add_edge()` function in `read_graf()`, and the IDE (aka cb) opens the main file for `stl_list`. Can anyone point out the problem? Thanks!

Here's the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<list>
#define grafMAX 101

FILE *fin = fopen("grafin.txt","r");
FILE *fout = fopen("grafout.txt","w");

struct Graf{
    int nrV;
    std::list <int> *ad;
};

void init_graf(Graf g, int nr){
    g.nrV = nr;
    g.ad = new std::list <int> [g.nrV];//(std::list <int> *)malloc(g.nrV * sizeof(std::list <int>));
}

void add_edge(Graf g, int n1, int n2){
    g.ad[n1].push_back(n2);
    g.ad[n2].push_back(n1);
}

inline int min(const int a, const int b){
    if(a < b)
        return a;
    return b;
}

void read_graf(Graf g){
    int n,m;
    fscanf(fin,"%d%d",&n,&m);
    init_graf(g,n);
    while(m){
        int x,y;
        fscanf(fin,"%d%d",&x,&y);
        add_edge(g,x,y);
        --m;
    }
}
```

Here's an input:

```
10 - # of nodes
11 - # of edges to be read
1 2
1 3
1 10
2 4
3 4
3 5
5 6
5 7
6 7
7 8
7 9
```

Comment: Not sure about the capabilities of your IDE, but have you tried a debugger that steps into that particular function call? It could be crashing on a null value for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `Graf` by value to the functions. This means that the changes are all made to *a copy* of the parameter you pass. The original is unchanged.

If you want the changes to be visible outside the function, you should pass a reference to the `Graf`, like `void init_graf(Graf& g, int nr)`.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error, though, even if I pass the value by reference.

Answer (score 1):

Before I start, this is a strange combination of both C coding style, with just a tiny amount of C++ thrown in to gain access to the List class. This is never a good idea. The majority of your code is written in C, so you should use C arrays obtained through malloc. If you want to use C++ List Class, then this program should be rewritten using C++ classes and include files and constructs.

On to your problem...

When you call init_graf, you are passing Graf G by value, so any initialization done by init_graf is lost when init_graf returns. You need to pass it by reference in C so you can update it.

Later, when you call add_edge, g is still uninitialized, and so the field "ad" is still uninitialized, so g.ad[n1] will dereference a bad pointer, causing an exception and your program will halt:

```
void add_edge(Graf g, int n1, int n2){
    g.ad[n1].push_back(n2);
    g.ad[n2].push_back(n1);
```

To fix this, init_graf should get a pointer to the Graf struct, likewise add_edge should get a pointer to g as well. Here is your solution with the use of the Class List removed (to make it a real C program).

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
// #include<list>
#define grafMAX 101

FILE *fin = fopen("grafin.txt","r");
FILE *fout = fopen("grafout.txt","w");

struct Edge {
     int startNode;
     int endNode; 
};

struct Graf{
    int  nrV;      
    int  edgeCount; // Added to keep track of number allocated
    Edge *ad;
};

void init_graf(Graf *g, int nr){
    g->nrV       = 0;
    g->edgeCount = nr; 
    g->ad = malloc(graphMax*sizeof(Edge));
}

void add_edge(Graf *g, int n1, int n2){
    // Check array bound before adding a new edge
    if (g->nrV < g->edgeCount) {
       // Add the edge to the edge array and increment nrV
       g->ad[g->nrV].startNode = n1;
       g->ad[g->nrV].endNode   = n2;
       g->nrV++;
    }
}

inline int min(const int a, const int b){
    if(a < b)
        return a;
    return b;
}

void read_graf(Graf *g){
    int n,m;
    fscanf(fin,"%d%d",&n,&m);
    init_graf(g,n);
    while(m){
        int x,y;
        fscanf(fin,"%d%d",&x,&y);
        add_edge(g,x,y);
        --m;
    }
}
```

If you really want to use C++, then Bo's suggestion of using & to pass the Graf parameter by reference is great, but then I suggest you then restructure your program to use classes rather than structs and use the C++ headers rather than C headers (cstdio rather than stdio.h for example)

Comment: This looks like a perfectly good C program. However, the question is tagged C++ and STL.  :-)

Comment: Thanks Bo. I agree that it is tagged C++, but I think the questioner was trying to just add in C++ Lists into a C program, so I suggested using a C array rather than trying to shoehorn in a C++ Class into an otherwise C program. If he really wants C++, I would suggest rewrting it and use the standard C++ headers, classes instead of structs, etc.

Comment: Thanks ScottK for the suggestion. I know my coding style (or what I like to call my coding style) is a bit messed-up, as I am transitioning from C to C++. Even if C++ brings new and powerful mechanics (OOP), I still like some C syntax elements, such as pointers to files and scanf and printf, as they give me more control over what I'm reading/ writing than streams. This is all just an opinion.

Comment: No problem SongBird, C has some great features and they are all available for use within C++. I have taught C++ to students, and I think the best way to learn C++ is to jump in by not relying on any C header files (as a start). Switch to using the C++ headers, and start defining your structs as classes rather than structs. Classes accept the same syntax, but allow you more control to add methods and constructors. I can post a C++ equivalent for you if that helps, but perhaps you should try it yourself first. Good luck!

Comment: @ScottK I guess that in the C++ equivalent you would've created a class Graf and you'd have implemented all the above functions as public methods. You'd also change the syntax from C to C++ (from scanf to streams etc.).

Comment: @theSongbird Exactly!